# Ocaml - parameter type when checking for duplicates in a list

Tags: list, recursion, types, duplicates, ocaml

I've got a basic function which checks a list for duplicates and returns true if they are found, false otherwise.

```
    # let rec check_dup l = match l with
        [] -> false
      | (h::t) ->
        let x = (List.filter h t) in
        if (x == []) then
           check_dup t
        else
           true
    ;;
```

Yet when I try to use this code I get the error

```
    Characters 92-93:
          let x = (List.filter h t) in
                                 ^
    Error: This expression has type ('a -> bool) list
           but an expression was expected of type 'a list
```

I don't really understand why this is happening, where is the a->bool list type coming from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type `('a -> bool) list` is coming from the type of `filter` and from the pattern match `h::t` in combination.  You're asking to use a single element of the list, `h`, as a *predicate* to be applied to every element of the list `t`.   The ML type system cannot express this situation.   `filter` expects two arguments, one of some type `'a -> bool` where `'a` is unknown, and a second argument of type `'a list`, where `'a` is the *same* unknown type as in the first argument.   So `h` must have type `'a -> bool` and `t` must have type `'a list`.

But you have also written `h::t`, which means that there is *another* unknown type `'b` such that `h` has type `'b` and `t` has type `'b list`.   Put this together and you get this set of equations:

```
'a -> bool == 'b
'a list == 'b list
```

The type checker looks at this and decides maybe `'a == 'b`, yielding the simpler problem

```
'a -> bool == 'a
```

and it can't find any solution, so it bleats.

Neither the simpler form nor the original equation has a solution.

---

You are probably looking for `List.filter (fun x -> x = h) t`, and you would probably be even better off using `List.exists`.

Answer (score 0):

For complete this answer I post the final function for search duplicate value in array:

```
let lstOne = [1;5;4;3;10;9;5;5;4];;

let lstTwo = [1;5;4;3;10];;

let rec check_dup l = match l with
    [] -> false
    | (h::t) ->
       let x = (List.filter (fun x -> x = h) t) in
         if (x == []) then
            check_dup t
         else
       true;;
```

and when the function run:

```
# check_dup lstOne

- : bool = true

# check_dup lstTwo

- : bool = false

#
```